# No Shapely geometry can be created from null value during dissolve in Geopandas?

Tags: python, dissolve, geopandas

```
d1= gpd.read_file(aq.shp)
asttom = gpd.read_file(es.shp)
data2 = d1[d1['TYPE'].str.startswith(('01'))]
dslv=data2.dissolve(by='TYPE')
```

While it reaches the dissolve procedure it causes the error. How to work with it?

Comment: Have you looked at what data2 returns? The error is telling you that you are dissolving a null. So the select might not be returning anything

Comment: Issue is because you are dissolving 'data2' and it must be doing with d1 (a geopandas geodataframe). **data2**, with 'TYPE' starting with '01', must be created as a geopandas geodataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is because you are dissolving 'data2' and it must be doing with d1 (a geopandas geodataframe). My following example works nicely:

```
import geopandas as gpd

path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp"

d1 = gpd.read_file(path)
data = d1['counts']
dslv = d1.dissolve(by='counts')

print dslv
```

and result, as it expected, is:

```
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
execfile(u'/home/zeito/pyqgis_scripts/using_shapely_geometry.py'.encode('UTF-8'))
                                                 geometry  FID          area  \
counts                                                                         
20      (POLYGON ((425341.4022431545 4428919.808172906 3.0  2.134534e+08   
100     POLYGON ((450747.2094816907 4445981.551269374, 2.0  3.737159e+08   
300     POLYGON ((363445.8816669167 4460178.914137968, 0.0  1.389711e+08   
500     POLYGON ((410566.1276510805 4463034.251804442, 1.0  2.805022e+08   

        class  cno  field     max     min  mult my_string  name  perimeter  \
counts                                                                       
20          2    3      0  2914.0  1364.0     1   my test    34  56801.054   
100         4    2      1  2962.0  1438.0     1   my test    64  76584.033   
300         1    0      1  2738.0  1538.0     1   my test    81  47573.201   
500         3    1      1  2330.0  1351.0     1   my test    27  65657.871   

        values  
counts          
20          33  
100         65  
300         31  
500         43
```

Original shapefile is:

[image]